# Compare files in Visual Studio easier

Tags: c#, ide, visual-studio-2015, add-in

Does anyone know of an extension/add-in to visual studio 2015 that lets me mark two (different) files in solution explorer, right-click, and display the same Compare window used with source control?

I can use compare on one file and get the dialog window where I can replace the TFS path with a path to the second file, but this is a time-consuming operation as I tend to compare quite often (I have an external tool that updates two or more data files in my project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend you [CodeCompare](https://www.devart.com/codecompare/).
The free version has a ton of features and has an amazing visual studio and eclipse integration. The option for comparing is mind bogeling. Trully amazing tool that actually also looks very nice.

It is a standalone tool, but also integrates seamless into VS

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try